# Unknown game data compression method (Gamecube)

Tags: file-format, decompress

I got some game compression data which I couldn't find any clue.
All compressed file signature start with: [*SK_ASC*] and unknown compression method.

I got some information from RAM/Executive file but still didn't work.
I think the compression is the lossless format (But it's not a LZO nor ZLIB).
Can anyone help me figure out the compression, and how to decompress?

- All of example file above can be found here: **http://goo.gl/JJQfl4**

**=== 10.25.14 ADDED ===**

The list below compression method that I tested, but doesn't match:

- LZ10
- LZ11
- LZ77
- LZO1x-1
- LZO1x-999
- LZSS
- LZW
- LZMA
- HUFF blocksize 4 & 8 byte
- RLE
- ZLIB

**=== 10.26.14 ADDED ===**

Today I analysis something via memory dump.

First of all, compressed `EMnMenu.cmp` file could be loaded when I enter the main menu by guessing it's file name. and there are very similar files which is unused. (`EKisokMenu.cmp`, `EE3Menu.cmp`)

So I try to check memory dump by replacing file each other. and I got `dump_menu.ram`, `dump_e3menu.ram`, `dump_kioskmenu.ram`. By comparing three different ram dump data, 
I found out only specific offset data is changed.

By using this method, I finally got a decompression data dumped via offset: **0x80CA6980**. Decompressed data is well known texture which was first 4 byte signature  start with 0x00 0x20 0xAF 0x30. (check texture format here: *http://goo.gl/UqLz3m*)

I try to find compression algorithm by compressing the decompression data and compare with original data. but non of algorithm that I test above doesn't match.

Anyway, I uploaded several decompressed data via ram dump and compressed data so you can check here: **goo.gl/JJQfl4**

- **CMP** is a compressed data which always start with *SK_ASC*.
- **BIN** is a same as CMP.
- **DCMP** is a instant copy from memory file, which was extracted from offset 0x80CA6980.
- **DMP** is a data value correction by subtracted 0x80CA6980 because there so many memory scrapping dummy (so this is the cleaned decompressed data if I guess right)

**ADDED** Didn't work with regular deflate/zlib all compress level.

**== 11.09.14 ==**

I posted several forum to help, but no clue for weeks :(

- http://zenhax.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=313&sid=3172c154c5da95476795ac742501fec1
- http://encode.ru/threads/2074-Identifying-compression-method?p=41188&posted=1#post41188

**== 11.15.14 ==**

Other forum user said to me there are Gamecube DOL (executive file) plugin for IDA.
So I use them and now I've found decompression main/algorithm subroutine.
Would anyone help me find out describe how it works?

(I'm not well in dis-assembly, So I'm learning now)

http://goo.gl/2bQNfj

**Power PC based Dis-Assembly skill Required**

Comment: You should run `signsrch` on the binary doing decompression, not the compressed data. Though it's quite likely the algorithm is completely custom and you'll just have to reverse it.

Comment: According to http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:G32DNOBV_QoJ:forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D21%26t%3D12093, `SK_ASC` is used for at least one game developed by [Silicon Knights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Knights). The `SK` suggests that this is using an algorithm that's proprietary to Silicon Knights, as @IgorSkochinsky suggested.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, I used 'signsrch' on Executive/Memory file, not a compressed data. Anyway, algorithm is quite mess and still no clue.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the correct files? At a glance, they look very similar, and neither starts with `SK_ASC`.

Comment: What I mean is it seems you uploaded the memory dump twice. I don't see the signature in either.

Comment: @Jongware I uploaded different data. DCMP is original decompressed dump data from 0x80CA6980 without touched. DMP is data value offset correction which was subtracted memory offset 0x80CA6980.

Comment: and It seems that [SK_ASC] signature disappeared after the decompression.

Comment: If `SK_ASC` is the signature for a compressed file, it is rather logically that it disappears. Here is an interesting factoid, though: using `gzip -9` on EE3Menu.dcmp (2253536 bytes) results in 1052810 bytes, while the compressed version is 1047680 bytes -- smaller than `gzip`! So at least it's not a standard-but-encrypted compression.

Comment: Where's your disasm?  All I see is a python decompilation.